# How to get components from a react library being rendered as html only in astrojs?

Tags: vite, astrojs

I am trying to combine astrojs and a react library (using this one: https://github.com/Timonwa/demo-ui-library/ as an example, but could be any).
I wish to use the react components as pure html (no javascript).

For simplicity, I clone the react library directly under `src/components/` in the astro tree. I then have an example index.astro as follows:

```html
---
import Button from '../components/demo-ui-library/src/components/Button/Button.tsx'
---

<Button client:only="react"></Button>
```

It works ok. However, when removing the `client:only="react"`, I get error `__vite_ssr_import_1__.default.button is not a function`. I was hoping to get the button being rendered as pure html (no javascript), but obviously this fails.

How to get components from a react library being rendered as html only in astrojs? Guidance would be more than welcome...

[edit: I expect this is somehow linked to inappropriate configuration settings, possibly related to vite]